# How would I skin a quad that is skewed with instances of a patch of quads?

Tags: geometry, game-engine, game-physics, blender

I have a system I use to generate terrain in blender game engine,
I use a regular grid and spawn in instances of a splat mapped tile to fill the grid (splat mapping allows vertex color to set texture)

as the actor moves, it takes unused tiles from far away and slaps them ahead

this works really really well, but now I want to skin a cubesphere

I can get the faces, but how does one skew a grid to match a quad?
(I need to fill the polygon with a regular grid of instaces of subdivided planes)
[image: cube w/grid and cubesphere w/grid]

[image]

here is what the system looks like in a 2d grid / infinite plane
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7EkQOWYxbc

so the blue plane is 1 patch, and there will be multiple patches per Quad.

currently I just slap the origin to the grid location and move the vertex up/down based on noise, I know that approach wont work here.

[system at work on a plane - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7EkQOWYxbc ]

Comment: Look into how uv's are mapped. If it was unwrapped, the uv system could deform a square from the image texture onto the deformed quad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it! quad corners = v1, v2, v3, v4

origin = (v1+v2+v3+v4)/4

p1.125 =( (p1*7)+p2)/8

p1.25 = ((p1*3)+p2)/4

etc
I can use this to adress the points in normal space, and set them in skew space :D

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xe-QYqvILlY this planet uses the technique